# Undefined url parameter in Angular 11

Tags: angular, url

I'm trying to pass a url parameter which I recieve from a get request, to Contracts component but when I vist the Contracts component in the url the passed parameter is undefined.
That is what I have done so far:

Into app-routing fle:
`{path: '',  component: PoliciesGridComponent}, {path: 'contracts/:Dsc', component: ContractsComponent}`

My initial component form where I pass the url paramter:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let policy of life | keyvalue | slice:0:1;"             
      >
        <a [routerLink]= "['/contracts', policy.Dsc]"
          routerLinkActive="active" class="noLinksDecoration">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <img src="../../assets/images/Component62_1.svg"> 
          <p class="policyTitle">Ζωή & Υγεία</p>
          <p class="counter">{{countLife}}</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>



Into contracts component where I access the url parametr I passed

     this.category = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.Dsc; //access url param
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use paramMap like this

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("Dsc")
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Hmm..it doesn't work also

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your code or replicate it and share?